# How can I modify Google's geocoding sample to output the current geolocation to HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geolocation

I can get my current location ([using this Google Maps API sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation)). I would like to output the resulting coordinates to HTML (in a similar way to [This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adhikariaman01/ocjenyc8/)).

I believe the JSFiddle uses this code to extract the coordinates, though I am not interested in the 'dragging' functionality:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) 
{
    document.getElementById("lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById("long").value = event.latLng.lng();
});
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) { console.log(position) })` would this not work for you?

Comment: What does your code look like that attempts to do that?

Comment: @PedroEstrada Although not what I used in the end, this was invaluable because it helped me reach my solution, which I shall post in a sec. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was able to output the lat and lng coordinates to HTML by inserting

```
document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = pos.lat;
document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = pos.lng;
```

below `map.setCenter(pos);`.

I then called it in HTML with:

```
<div id="lat"></div>
<div id="lng"></div>
```

Here is the output:

[image: Geolocation with coordinates displayed]